# Algorand's Verifiable Random Function (VRF) implementation

Tags: c, linux, encryption, cryptography, libsodium

I have been trying for a while to compile the VRF implementation that algorand open-sourced more than a year ago (available [here](https://github.com/algorand/libsodium)). There is little to no documentation, so I haven't able to do it. I have tried in both Mac OS and Linux without much luck. It seems like the installation scripts on their fork of libsodium just skip compiling the VRF files. With so much code, is difficult to get what is the error. Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.0.16 release doesn't seem to include the VRF files at all.  One change mentions `crypto_vrf.c`, but that is not in the tarball.

Cloning the repository includes `crypto_vrf.c` and the code was compiled.

Use:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:algorand/libsodium.git
cd libsodium
sh autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

This recipe appeared to work fine on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.14.6 Mojave, both when using the Xcode `clang` compiler and when using my home-built GCC 9.3.0 (`gcc`).  I would expect the same recipe to work on Linux too.

The recipe given does assume you have sufficiently modern versions of the 'AutoTools' — `autoconf`, `automake`, `libtool` (and `m4`).  They don't have to be all that modern.  I have `autoconf` v2.69 (copyright date: 2012) and `automake` v1.15 (copyright date: 2015) — and used `/usr/bin/m4` and the `libtool` included in the package.  I compiled `autoconf` and `automake` so that they're installed in `/opt/gnu/bin` (though you could probably get pre-built sets using Brew or one of the other systems for obtaining open source packages for macOS).